# Create custom category navigation wordpress

Tags: wordpress, navigation, categories

I want to create a custom category navigation 3 level in wordpress.
I don't want to use php wp_nav_menu(), because i need to add cateogry thumbnail inside the navigation.
I found this code :

```
<?php // Create category navigation with posts for each subcat
    $categories = get_categories();
    $catID = $cat->cat_ID;
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        if($cat->category_parent == 0){ //If is a top level category
            $subcategories = get_categories('child_of='. $cat->cat_ID);
            if (count($subcategories)>0){ ?>

                <li class="haschild"><a><?php echo $cat->name; ?><span class="image"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></span></a>

                <?php } /* end if has subcats */
            else { // else; does not have childen ?>

                <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->cat_ID); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a><span class="image"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></span></li>

            <?php } //end else ?>
        <?php // Get the subcats !!! THIS RETURNS ALL DECENDING LEVELS. 
            $subcategories = get_categories('child_of='. $cat->cat_ID);
            if (count($subcategories)>0){
                echo "<ul class='sub-menu'>";
                foreach ($subcategories as $scat) { ?>

                <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $scat->cat_ID); ?>"><?php echo $scat->name; ?><span class="image"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($scat->term_id); ?>" /></span></a></li>



            <?php
            echo "";
             }
            echo "</ul> </li>"; // Close the Child UL DIV and parent LI
            }   //endif has subcats ?>

        <?php } //end if parent ?>
    <?php } //end foreach ?>
```

But it doesn't work on 3 level, just on 2 level.
you can look the menu directly on my website : http://www.designsd.fr/ap/

Do you have an idea to change it ?

Comment: Look at the code logic: it does a loop inside the main loop to get the child categories. Just replicate the code about subcats and place it inside the subcat loop.

Comment: Yes i know i try to do that but i'm not a developer, just a front-end. Can you help me to write the correct version of the new loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code with a new loop level:

```
<?php // Create category navigation with posts for each subcat
$categories = get_categories();
$catID = $cat->cat_ID;
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    if($cat->category_parent == 0){ //If is a top level category
        $subcategories = get_categories('child_of='. $cat->cat_ID);
        if (count($subcategories)>0){ ?>

        <li class="haschild"><a><?php echo $cat->name; ?><span class="image"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></a></span>

            <?php } /* end if has subcats */
        else { // else; does not have childen ?>

            <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->cat_ID); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a><span class="image"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" /></span></li>

        <?php } //end else ?>
    <?php // Get the subcats !!! THIS RETURNS ALL DECENDING LEVELS. 
        $subcategories = get_categories('child_of='. $cat->cat_ID);
        if (count($subcategories)>0){
            echo "<ul class='sub-menu'>";
            foreach ($subcategories as $scat) {
                $child_subcategories = get_categories('child_of='. $scat->cat_ID);
                if (count($child_subcategories)>0){ ?>
                    <li class="test"><a><?php echo $scat->name; ?><span class="image"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($scat->term_id); ?>" /></span></a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $scat->cat_ID); ?>"><?php echo $scat->name; ?><span class="image"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($scat->term_id); ?>" /></a></span>
                <?php }
                if (count($child_subcategories)>0){
                    echo "<ul class='sub-menu'>";
                    foreach ($child_subcategories as $sscat) { ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $sscat->cat_ID); ?>"><?php echo $sscat->name; ?><span class="image"><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($sscat->term_id); ?>" /></span></a></li>
                    <?php }
                    echo '</ul>';
                }
                ?>
                </li>
                <?php;
             }
            echo "</ul> </li>"; // Close the Child UL DIV and parent LI
        }   //endif has subcats ?>

    <?php } //end if parent ?>
<?php } //end foreach ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It's almost that.
The problems are persisting
- When you click on a second level link (more... ) that has a sub-menu, this one have a href link so he reloads the page.
- Links ( archive 1 / archive 2 and archive 3 ) should not appear in level 2 but the third level of (more ... )

Comment: Do you want to avoid to link to the current category that is being displayed, or unlink all categories that have childs?

Comment: Unlink all categories that have childs

Comment: It's almost that, now the last problem is Links ( archive 1 / archive 2 and archive 3 ) should not appear in level 2 but only on the third level of (more ... ). Look : http://designsd.fr/ap/

Comment: My bad there was a typo in the code. Look on the updated version, it should be ok now.

Comment: Look, i update the code i go look : http://designsd.fr/ap/category/travel/guayane/ There is always the problem for archive 1 / archive 2 / archive 3 that appaear on 2nd level and i don't want

Comment: It seems it doesn't go into the condition `if (count($child_subcategories)>0)` - you're sure you changed this condition (previously it was wrong)?

Comment: i don't change this condition. Previously it doesn't work too. I just changed the <a></a> inside the loop.